# HTML/CSS "float: right" causing form to be moves out of line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to have a form be aligned with a row of text in HTML. Both the row of text and the form are displayed inline, but whenever I float the form to the right, it seemingly moves down and out of line with the text. I don't know what is causing this, as when it is not floated it displays perfectly in line. Thanks!

The problem:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="/home.php">Home</a>
    <div style="float: right;">
        <form action="/signup.php" method="post" style="display: inline !important;">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Home</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

```html
<li class="list-group-item">
  <a href="/home.php">Home</a>
  <div style="float: right;">
    <form action="/signup.php" method="post" style="display: inline !important;">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Home</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Please add link to page, or more code where the problem is. Your current code is working, 'Home' and form are both in the same line. https://jsfiddle.net/2q3n085z/

Comment: @panther He is required to post his markup here, not a jsfiddle. That will get this question closed even quicker. [mcve]

Comment: Lets not forget to request the related CSS code. Hard to solve a problem without all of the data.-- Sorry, I suppose that would be included in Rob's request for the "minimal reproducible example"...

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="row">
      <a href="/home.php">Home</a>
      <form action="/signup.php" method="post">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Home</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Use **flex** instead of **float**. You can easily achieve the result by giving **justify-content:space-between** to the flex box. Also remove style="display: inline !important;" from the form element. Please see the code snippet.